# itemize vs list

Tags: lists, itemize

I've come across two ways to display lists, `\begin{list}` and `\begin{itemize}`. I couldn't find any information on the `list` environment. What is the difference between the two?

Here is a simple example:

```
\begin{list}{--}{}
    \item This bullet is within a \verb|\begin{list}|
    \item This is a second bullet
\end{list}
\begin{itemize}
    \renewcommand\labelitemi{--}
    \item This bullet is within a \verb|\begin{itemize}|
    \item This is a second bullet
\end{itemize}
```

[image: The two commands, shown together]

Comment: It would help if you could post compilable code. You don't normally invoke `list` directly in a document at all.

Comment: @ebo There is something like `easy list` or something. I thought maybe you had that in mind. (That can't be the right name, though, with the space.)

Answer (score 37, accepted):

`list` is a basic LaTeX environment used to create list environments of all kinds, including `itemize`, `enumerate` and the `description` environments, as well as the 'trivial' list environments used for such things as quotations and abstracts.

You don't usually use the `list` environment directly in documents. Instead, it is used to create higher level environments, such as `itemize`, for use in documents.

Before packages such as `enumitem` were available, custom `description`, `itemize` and `enumerate` environments were created in this way. (Of course, they still can be, but `enumitem` makes it unnecessary in most cases.)

Here's an example specifying a simple variant on the `description` environment.

```
\documentclass{article}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\labelpethau}[1]{\textsc{#1:}}
\newlength\normalparindent
\setlength\normalparindent{\parindent}
\newenvironment{pethau}%
{\begin{list}{}%
    {\renewcommand{\makelabel}{\labelpethau}%
      \setlength{\itemindent}{0pt}%
      \setlength{\leftmargin}{0pt}%
      \setlength{\labelwidth}{-1\normalparindent}%
      \addtolength{\topsep}{-0.5\parskip}%
      \listparindent \normalparindent
      \setlength{\parsep}{\parskip}}}%
  {\end{list}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{pethau}
  \item[Question] some of what?
  \item[Answer] anything.
\end{pethau}
\end{document}
```

[image: customised list]

Answer (score 13):

The `itemize` environment is a special case of the `list` environment.  The `list` environment is more general: you can do more things with it.  For instance,

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}

\begin{list}{\color{blue}$\heartsuit$}{\color{red}}
\item first item
\item second item
\item third item
\end{list}

\end{document}
```

[image]