# How do you prevent the "list" environment from printing out the spacing before the list?

Tags: lists, itemize, enumitem

When using `\begin{list}{-}{1em}`, my expected result would be

```
- List item
- List item
```

However, it displays as:

```
  1em
- List item
- List item
```

or

```
1em
- List item
- List item
```

EDIT: Minimal working example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
    \begin{list}{-}{1em}
        \item I 1
        \item I 2
    \end{list}
\end{document}
```

prints as

```
1em
- I 1
- I 2
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX!! Rather than posting code fragments it is better to give a full [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228). Currently we have to guess what packages etc you are using and this makes it really hard to help you. A MWE should start with a `\documentclass` command, have a minimal preamble  and then `\begin{document}...\end{document}`. The code should compile and be as small as possible to demonstrate your problem. From your question it looks like you are using a package that styles lists but I have no idea which one so it is impossible to help.

Comment: (1) what is not how the `list` works, the second arg is for commands to run to control the look. (2) why don't you just use the `enumitem` package, it provides a much easier interface than low level `list`. (3) the `list` syntax is explain here: http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/base/source2e.pdf#page=299&zoom=auto,-196,844 and on the preceeding pages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second parameter of `\begin{list}` takes more than just a spacing argument. For examples of what it is used for check [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/375610/itemize-vs-list).

Additionally in that answer it is mentioned that the `list` environment is not intended for general use, but rather use the `itemize`, `enumerate`, or `description` environments.

A solution would be to use `itemize` in your case:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
    \begin{itemize}
        \item[-] I 1
        \item[-] I 2
    \end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

or this variation if you don't want to customize the list symbol every time:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
    \begin{itemize}
        \renewcommand\labelitemi{-}
        \item I 1
        \item I 2
    \end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

To change the separation between elements in `itemize` you can use the `enumitem` package. Like so:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}
    \begin{itemize}[label={-},noitemsep]
        \item I 1
        \item I 2
    \end{itemize}
\end{document}
```